# User interface in Java doubts

Tags: java, user-interface

I have to create a user interface in Java, I asked in another forum for some recommendations and somebody answered me, at that moment, few people write GUI application in JAVA, its most used .NET, could somebody help me?.
Thanks
Maria

Comment: The Java Tutorials - [Trail: Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: google `GUI application in Java` only get 9 million hits, but that  doesn't sound like a few to me. https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=+gui+application+in+java&*

Comment: .NET is C# and not java

Answer (score 1):

The way with java gui is to use javaFx. For that you'll need java 8 (no other lib is needed). This is easier to use as Swing or AWT before. Also its fancier by default.
Although its somehow not new to the community(2 years), there can be some pitfalls you will run into. By now i don't see a better solution. If you need more native "look and feel" you can use the platform dependent swt which is somehow old, proofed but harder to use.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm